# How can you trim numbers and underscores out of a string?

Tags: php, regex

So I have a file `6647_241_file1.pdf` and I need to get rid of the `6647_241_` part of the filename.

My original name comes from a row, but I created what I was doing below in a simple way.

```
<?php
$string=$row[file_name];
```

becomes:

```
$string="6647_241_file1.pdf";

$string1 = preg_replace("/*._/", "", $string);
echo $string1; 
?>
```

I was just trying this but haven't been successful at it.  The numbers change, so I wasn't sure of a universal way to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp `/^[\d_]*/`

```
$string="6647_241_file1.pdf";

$string1 = preg_replace("/^[\d_]*/", "", $string);
echo $string1;
```

Should echo: `file1.pdf`

What does it do:

1. `^` means look at the begining of the string
2. `[]` means group a couple of characters or characterclasses together as one
3. `\d` is the character class for digits which are numbers
4. `_` is what it is the character himself
5. `*` means the group `[]` can accour zero or more times

In one sentence:
Select all numbers and underscores from the beginning till something else comes.

Comment: The explanation really clarified it for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are regexes and explodes, etc.  But here's one fun way:

```
$result = ltrim($string, '0123456789_');
```

Use `trim()` if you want to trim both ends.

Comment: That worked! ;)  I tried ltrim before but messed up the syntax, this made it easy!